# flask hangs right before return jsonify ((no output error ))

Tags: json, ajax, python-3.x, flash, flask-login

I'm a new dev , I've made a page that check if user is logged on load and if he is it replace the login forms with some other data from the server

on the other hand if not it shows the login forms and wait for the user to click login to trigger another ajax to verify and pull user info and return Json object with it .

the problem occurs Right before the return line - i traced back the problem with print and log on js , everything works fine before the return jsonify line

the weird part is it never raises any error it just hangs

```
 def clogin():

print(f"\n login activated \n")
if request.method == "POST":
    loginName = request.form.get("memberNameid")
    loginPw = request.form.get("passwordloginid")
    #session['user'] = loginName


    f = Users.query.filter_by(email=loginName).first()
    login_user(f)
    session['user'] = f
    print(f"I have receved this from AJAX ... \n \n loginName = {loginName} \n loginPw = {loginPw} \n current_user = {current_user} \n current_user.id = {current_user.id} \n current_user.name = {current_user}")
    print(f"f.email = {f.email} \n f.pw = {f.password}")

    if f:
        qdisplayname = f.name
        print("qdisplayname = ",qdisplayname)
        if f.email == loginName: #and sha256_crypt.verify(loginPw,f.qpw):
            if f.pos == "pos2":
                print("pos : pos 2 was picked ")

                return jsonify({"Success": True , "Msg":" lets try to get jinja to work - email {{ current_user.email }} " , "position" : "Pharmacist" , "displayname":current_user.name })
```

here is CMD output :

login activated

I have receved this from AJAX ...

```
loginName = qwe@qwe.qwe
loginPw = qwe
current_user = <Users 1>
current_user.id = 1
current_user.name = <Users 1>
f.email = qwe@qwe.qwe
f.pw = qwe
qdisplayname =  name2
pos : pos 2 was picked
```

please let me know if you have any idea what makes flask hangs like this ?
i cant even refresh or navigate to a different page i have to shutdown the server

Comment: have recently runned into a similar issue... have you found out what the reason was back then?

Comment: @MartinBucher I've just answered my own question just for you, when I checked the old file I have noticed that I used flask_login instead, it's the most reliable to handle the login requests in my opinion.

Comment: ok so no jsonify({}) anymore... i really think it's smth weird about it. couldn't reproduce this in the past days, maybe it's already fixed. but thx anways!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up relaying on `flask_login` to handle the login requests.

The login function has become as the following:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

login_form = LoginForm()

# Allow login if validation success
if login_form.validate_on_submit():
    x = users.query.filter_by(username=login_form.username.data).first()
    login_user(x)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

return render_template("login.html", form=login_form)
```